# What is the best way to handle errors in plugins and templates?

Tags: templating, plugin-development

What's the best way to prevent exceptions in my plugin from blowing up my entire page? try/catch and return null, and then check for null in the template?

For example: my plugin fetches data from a remote REST API. If that request fails for any reason I get an error page. I understand why, but I'm looking for the best way to handle it. I'd appreciate any input, even if it seems glaringly obvious to you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep, Craft makes pretty liberal use of try/catch blocks. Wrap your HTTP request in that, and return whatever makes sense in the context – `null`, `false`, or maybe an empty array.

Probably also worth logging the error, so the developer can investigate why it’s not working, using `Craft::log()`.

Remember when catching exceptions, that there’s a good chance the exception class won’t be in Craft’s namespace. So you’ll probably need to prepend the exception class(es) with `\`.

So to put it all together:

```
try
{
    // Make the HTTP request
    // ...
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    Craft::log('The request to domain.com failed: '.$e->getMessage(),
               LogLevel::Warning, false, 'mypluginhandle');

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what I generally do if I want to catch exceptions but still output an error to the browser. This example uses Craft's included Guzzle class to make the http request.

```
try 
{
    // create client
    $client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client('https://twitter.com');

    // get response
    $response = $client->get()->send();
}
catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException $e) 
{
    // throw a craft exception which displays the error cleanly
    throw new HttpException(400, 'Internet connection not available');
}
```

You can of course do anything you want inside the catch block, such as rendering a template and providing it with information about the error:

```
$html = craft()->templates->render('error', array(
    'message' => 'Internet connection not available'
));
```

Comment: If the call was invoked from a template and I call craft()->templates->render, what's the result? Does the template rendered by this call replace the whole page?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that it simply returns html code but you can then do whatever you want with this.

Comment: @BenCroker Thanks for mentioning Guzzle in your answer. I've been completely missing out until now!

Comment: Guzzle is amazing!!